# Windows 10 Calculator showing in pseudo-local

Tags: windows-10, language, character-encoding, locale

I'm pretty new to windows 10, but my calculator app is showing in pseuedo-locale

How to I turn this off and have it display in normal English ?

[image]

Comment: You have posted the screenshot of calculator but you've mentioned it as calendar in your question.

Comment: Looks like someone has fixed...I did indeed mean Calculator.

Comment: It's calculator from `Windows Store apps`; uninstall it, then download from *Windows Store* (it's free) and install back

Answer (score 0):

New Windows 10 metro calc is problematic and limited in scope. But it is possible to use the old: http://winaero.com/blog/get-calculator-from-windows-8-and-windows-7-in-windows-10/